# Difference between AES 128 algorithm and RijndaelManaged - based on Oracle Compatibility

Tags: c#, oracle, algorithm, encryption

Could someone please help me in finding some information on AES and Rijndael Managed cryptography?

What I am looking for is to have a common encryption algorithm to be implemented between C# and Oracle. As per the Oracle Documentation it supports the algorithms: DES, 3DES, AES, RC4, 3DES_2KEY for encryption.

I am trying to implement salting also with AES 128. So this also is my concern on how to make it match up with the Oracle decryption.

Comment: AES and Rijndael means the same. Actually the Rijndael algorithm was the winner of the AES selection process done by [NIST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Standards_and_Technology)

Comment: Rijndael is a superset of AES and supports additional block and key sizes. AES is Rijndael with 128 bit blocks and 128, 192 or 256 bit keys.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "salting with AES". Salts are used with password hashes. Key based encryption like AES only works with IVs.